# Bayesian estimation of an econometric State Space Model [Need suggestions or feedback]

Tags: bayesian, econometrics, markov-chain-montecarlo, state-space-models, bayesian-optimization

I'm struggling to estimate the parameters $\theta_{t},\beta,\gamma,\sigma^{2}_{\epsilon},\sigma^{2}_{\eta}$ of the following model:

$y_{t}=\theta_{t}+\beta (y_{t-1}-\theta_{t-1})+\gamma' x_{t} + \epsilon_{t}, 
  \epsilon_{t} \sim N(0,\sigma^{2}_{\epsilon})$   **(Measurement equation)**

$\theta_{t}=2\theta_{t-1}-\theta_{t-2}+ \eta_{t}, 
  \eta_{t} \sim N(0,\sigma^{2}_{\eta})$ **(State equation)**

where $\eta_{t}$ and $\epsilon_{t}$ are assumed to be uncorrelated at all lags and leads, $y_{t}$ is the observed value and  $x_{t}$ a vector of (observed) exogenous variable at time $t$.

At a first glance, I found that the model is a bit tricky to be written in the general state space representation, say

$y_{t}=Z_{t}\alpha_{t} + \epsilon_{t}, 
  \epsilon_{t} \sim N(0,H_{t})$

$\alpha_{t+1}=T_{t}\alpha_{t}+R_{t}\eta_{t},
\eta_{t} \sim N(0,Q_{t})$.

Then, at the second look, it continued to be tricky..

My first attempt was to estimate using MCMC approach:

1. Give initial values $\beta^{(0)},\gamma^{(0)},\sigma^{2 (0)}_{\epsilon},\sigma^{2 (0)}_{\eta}$;
2. Setting $Z_{t}=(1,-\beta^{(0)},y_{t-1},x_{1,t},...,x_{k,t}), \alpha_{t}=(\theta_{t},\theta_{t-1},\beta^{(0)},\gamma^{(0)}_{1},...,\gamma^{(0)}_{k})$ and $T_{t}=\begin{bmatrix}A&0\\0&I_{k+1}\end{bmatrix}, A=\begin{bmatrix}2&-1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$, draw $\theta^{(0)}_{t}$ from $\theta_{t}|Y,\beta^{(0)},\gamma^{(0)},\sigma^{2 (0)}_{\epsilon},\sigma^{2 (0)}_{\eta}$ by making use of some simulation smoother (for instance, Durbin-Koopman);
3. Define $\Theta=(\beta,\gamma)$. Use the measurement equation to calculate the (normal) likelihood $\ell(\Theta,\sigma^{2}_{\epsilon})$, multiple it by the priors (for instance, Normal-inverse gamma) $p(\Theta|\sigma^{2}_{\epsilon}),p(\sigma^{2}_{\epsilon})$, and draw $(\beta^{(1)},\gamma^{(1)},\sigma^{2 (1)}_{\epsilon})$ from the posterior;
4. Given a prior $p(\sigma^{2}_{\eta})$, use the state equation to calculate $\ell(\sigma^{2}_{\eta})$, and then draw $\sigma^{2 (1)}_{\eta}$ from the posterior;
5. Repeat the steps 2-3 using the previous posteriors as priors untill convergence.

Do you agree with that? What alternative ways do I have? Could I avoid MCMC?